# How to add a ascending and descending button to sort a multidimensional array

Tags: php, html, arrays

I want to write a code in php which will sort the `nilai_pengetahuan` on my array in a txt file in ascending and descending order on clicking the respective buttons.

My Array

```
[
    {"nama":"Ryan","nilai_pengetahuan":"23","nilai_keterampilan":"76"},
    {"nama":"Hary","nilai_pengetahuan":"98","nilai_keterampilan":"89"},
    {"nama":"Ahmad","nilai_pengetahuan":"88","nilai_keterampilan":"77"},
    {"nama":"Rudi","nilai_pengetahuan":"69","nilai_keterampilan":"67"},
    {"nama":"Michi","nilai_pengetahuan":"23","nilai_keterampilan":"32"}
]
```

My code so far

```
<Input type="submit" name="asc" value="Ascending" class="btn btn-primary"></Input>
<Input type="submit" name="desc" value="Descending" class="btn btn-primary"></Input>
<?php 
$nilai = json_decode(file_get_contents('array.txt'), true);

foreach ($nilai as $value) {;

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>". $value['nama']; echo"</td>";
    echo "<td>". $value['nilai_pengetahuan']; echo"</td>";
    echo "<td>". $value['nilai_keterampilan']; echo"</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    } 


if (isset ($_POST ["asc"])){
  usort($nilai, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['nilai_pengetahuan'] <=> $b['nilai_pengetahuan'];
});
}
    
if (isset ($_POST ["desc"])){
  usort($nilai, function($a, $b) {
    return $b['nilai_pengetahuan'] <=> $a['nilai_pengetahuan'];
});
 }
      ?>
```

Comment: What did you want to ask?

Comment: i want some help

Comment: Perhaps you should not swap `$a` and `$b`, in both the function parameters and around the spaceship operator to get a descending order?

Comment: the button is still not working, its still not sorting

Comment: Ah, Wahyu Kristianto is on to something, see the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `foreach` after conditions :

```
$nilai = json_decode(file_get_contents('array.txt'), true);

if (isset ($_POST["asc"])){
    usort($nilai, function($a, $b) {
        return $a['nilai_pengetahuan'] <=> $b['nilai_pengetahuan'];
    });
}

if (isset ($_POST["desc"])){
    usort($nilai, function($a, $b) {
        return $b['nilai_pengetahuan'] <=> $a['nilai_pengetahuan'];
    });
}

foreach ($nilai as $value) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: idk why, but its still doesnt work

Comment: Can you `var_dump` `$_POST["asc"]` or `$_POST["desc"]`?

Comment: Check demo :  https://phpsandbox.io/e/x/stekf?layout=EditorPreview&defaultPath=%2F&theme=dark&showExplorer=no&openedFiles=

Comment: how about sorting both nilai_pengetahuan and keterampilan? how do i that?

Comment: var_dump($_POST); output : array(0) { }

Comment: The problem is your `$_POST` does't have `asc` or `desc`. So it's not sorted.

Comment: while if i use var_dump($_POST["asc"]), the output : Warning: Undefined array key "asc" in C:\xampp\htdocs\lsp\index.php on line 37
NULL

Comment: Yes it is. Since you don't have any POST, it will undefned error. How you define input `asc` or `desc`? With hidden form? Can you update your quetion, I will help

Comment: i use ` <Input type="submit" name="asc" value="Ascending" class="btn btn-primary"></Input>`
` <Input type="submit" name="desc" value="Descending" class="btn btn-primary"></Input>`

Comment: Is it for submit? Can you update your question, and include all form?

Comment: oh, thank you i noticed some mistakes i made while making the input. can you help me make the sorting so its sorting both of the nilai not just the nilai_pengetahuan?

Comment: It's different question, so you need to create a question. Saya akan mampir kalau keliatan :)

Comment: terima kasih banyak for the help!